# Laravel different queue driver usage with different connections

Tags: laravel, message-queue, amazon-sqs, supervisord

I would like to ask about laravel 5.8 different queue drivers usage with different queue connections.Is this possible? If you think it is, please kindly check the following.

I was testing to use Amazon SQS and at the same time I also want to use Amazon SQS FIFO using shiftonelabs/laravel-sqs-fifo-queue.

**My Queu Config is as follow.**

'connections' => [

```
    'sqs' => [
        'driver' => 'sqs',
        'key' => 'xxxxx',
        'secret' => 'xxxxx',
        'prefix' => 'https://sqs.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/xxxxx/',
        'queue' => 'queue_name_1',
        'region' => 'xxxxx',
    ],

    'sqs-fifo' => [
        'driver' => 'sqs-fifo',
        'key'    => 'xxxxx',
        'secret' => 'xxxxx',
        'prefix' => 'https://sqs.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/xxxxx/',
        'queue'  => 'queue_name_2',
        'region' => 'xxxxx',
        'group' => 'default',
        'deduplicator' => 'unique',
    ],



],
```

**Supervisor Config is as follows**.

```
[program:laravel-worker-ii]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/html/test_env/scheduler_test/artisan queue:work sqs sqs-fifo --timeout=30 --tries=3 --sleep=3
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
numprocs=50
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/tmp/worker-ii.log
```

**Job Controller**
First Job

```
$goodJob = (new DoSomethingGoodJob($data))->onQueue('queue_name_1');
$this->dispatch($goodJob);
```

Second Job

```
$betterJob = (new DoSomethingBetterJob($data))->onQueue('queue_name_2');
$this->dispatch($betterJob);
```

Comment: Are you trying to send the same job to 2 different queues? What is the expected result?

Comment: @ChristopheHubert I wanted to use different jobs with different queue drivers. I updated at config and added job dispatch code from controller.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do but the connection to be mentioned in supervisor would depend on which connection you dispatched your job. The connection you dispatched the job with should be the one mentioned in the supervisor config.

Comment: I have edited for how jobs will be dispatched using different queue names having different queue driver. Could the edited version could explain what I wanted?

Comment: The config file you mentioned is a listing of different connections, not queues. If you want to dispatch to specific connection do it like this:

$goodJob = (new DoSomethingGoodJob($data))->onConnection('sqs-fifo');
$this->dispatch($goodJob);